# Reaction Kinetics and Catalyst Addition

Tags: kinetics, catalysis, surface-chemistry

The addition of a catalyst is known to increase the rate constant of a reaction by providing an easier pathway for the reaction to occur, one with lesser activation energy.

*My doubt is:*

Is it possible that the addition of a catalyst, alters the **order of a reaction**?

I haven't come across any such reaction so far, so it'd be great if someone could provide an example as well; *if* the reaction order can be changed upon addition of catalyst

*My thoughts:*

Sometimes, catalysts participate in the reaction; but are regenerated in the end without change in mass and chemical composition. 
The very fact that a catalyst can *participate* in a reaction, should mean that it can influence the reaction's order, right?

Comment: It certainly can. In most situations, the resting state has free catalyst, and if the catalyst is involved in the transition state of the rate determining step, then the catalyst concentration enters into the rate law for the catalyzed reaction.

Comment: Ohh! Could you please provide a more specific example, in which the catalyst concentration influences the rate law?

Comment: You can pick like any example you can think of.